# I am having problems with for loop. repeats values in mysql

Tags: php, for-loop, laravel

My controller

```
for($a=0; $a<count($area_id); $a++)
{
  for($i=0; $i<count($estimated_time); $i++)
   {
      $project_area = new Projectarea;
      $project_area->area_id = $area_id[$a];
      $project_area->project_id = $project->id;
      $project_area->estimated_time = $estimated_time[$i];
      $project_area->save();
    }
}
return Redirect::to('admin');
```

my view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select_client">Choose area</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="area_id[]"  multiple="multiple">
     @foreach($area as $row)
        <option class="click" value="{{ $row->id }}" area="{{ $row->id }}">{{$row->area_name}}</option>
     @endforeach
     </select>

    @foreach($area as $row)
      <input class="other" id="{{ $row->id }}" type="text" name="estimated_time[]" placeholder="{{ $row->area_name }}" />
    @endforeach
</div>
```

mysql result.

if i select for example three values from multiple select i have this result in database

```
project_id  area_id estimated_time
123           7          0
123           7          2
123           7          3
123           7          4
123           7          0
123           8          0
123           8          2
123           8          3
123           8          4
123           8          0
123           9          0
123           9          2
123           9          3
123           9          4
123           9          0
124           8          0
```

Thank you

Comment: What kind of output you want? As per my understanding you are using two for loops in which if one value is found another loop will run with same value then agiain it will take another one with prev for loop and do the same.

Comment: This is kind of project task idea. When create a project, the estimated time for project is defined the time of each area required for the project. I have three tables for that since it is a many to many relationship. For example this project will take 40 hours web development, 30 hours design etc. i tried to put in one loop the two variable , $estimated_time and $area_id i have a error undefined offset 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is due to double foreach, you foreach too many time.

3 value selected = 3 loop (`for($a=0; $a<count($area_id); $a++)`) * n loop for every estimated_time (`for($i=0; $i<count($estimated_time); $i++)`)

So remove second foreach and acces POST via array :

```
var_dump($_POST);
for($a=0; $a<count($_POST['area_id']); $a++)
{

    var_dump($_POST['estimated_time'][$_POST['area_id'][$a]]);
    var_dump($_POST['area_id'][$a]);
    echo 'insert';

}
```

Edit : it s a correction our your code, but your concption still wrong

Comment: I tried like this but it works only if i select options from select in ascending order. otherwise it will assign or shift the value of previous to the next one.

Comment: Why you make an array for estimated_time ? You can do like this `estimated_time[{{ $row->id }}]` and acces this value like this `$_POST['estimated_time'][$_POST['area_id'][$a]]`

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand from your question, however, if I understand it right you are trying to insert estimated time for project based on location. The problem was that you actually don't need the inner for loop, since, estimated_time array and area_id array would actually be of same size.

Please try following code:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($area_id); $i++)
{
      $project_area = new Projectarea;
      $project_area->area_id = $area_id[$i];
      $project_area->project_id = $project->id;
      $project_area->estimated_time = $estimated_time[$i];
      $project_area->save();
}
return Redirect::to('admin');
```